# Need help fixing this program

Tags: java

How should I write the program so that it takes the user's input and assigns it to the variable age and then runs the code?

```
public class Callone 
{
    public void print_det()
    {
        int age = y;
        if(age > 25)
            System.out.println("Not Valid");
        else
            System.out.println("Valid");
     }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the age of the applicant");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Callone c = new Callone();
        c.print_det();
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem did you face with your above code?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Callone {

    public void print_det(int y)
    {
        int age = y;
        if(age > 25)
        System.out.println("Not Valid");
        else
            System.out.println("Valid");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the age of the applicant");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Callone c = new Callone();
        c.print_det(y);
    }
}
```

when running in eclipse, console while halt for user input type in number and hit enter you should see output

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your `y` variable there:

```
int age = y;
```

You have to pass it using method parameter:

```
public class Callone 
{
    public void print_det(int y)
    {
        int age = y;
        if(age > 25)
            System.out.println("Not Valid");
        else
             System.out.println("Valid");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the age of the applicant");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Callone c = new Callone();
        c.print_det(y);
    }
}
```

To make it more "sweet":

```
public class Callone 
{
    public void print_det(int age)
    {
        if(age > 25)
            System.out.println("Not Valid");
        else
             System.out.println("Valid");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the age of the applicant");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Callone c = new Callone();
        c.print_det(age);
    }
}
```

Not tested.